# Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, coding-standards

I am checking coding standards of my module. I face this warning in technical report

> Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
) {
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

For Ex: Here is total 7 lines, I face error at line no 3 even line 2 and 3 have same spaces.

I am using sublime text editor.

How we found that we make tab or space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click at the start of that line and then click right arrow key.  If it directly jump after 4 spaces then you have used tab there.  Otherwise it will take you four click to reach 4 places.

I will suggest use of the text editor like **Php storm**.  In it you can directly select and convert all the tabs into spaces.